# Unable to make flexbox container responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a learning project where I have some profile cards stacked together with the help of flexbox. Though I have been learning flexbox for a couple of days, I still couldn't wrap my head around making a page responsive with the help of flexbox. So I have this page with 4 items on it. Right now the items are kind of fixed. It doesn't respond to screen sizes. But what I want to do is to move an item to the next row when the screen size is small or move an item to the top row if the screen size is big but keeping the items on the center of the whole container(as shown in Codepen). W3school has something like this:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_wrap

I tried this with `flex-wrap: wrap;` but my items doesn't respond at all. Here are the codepen and my code:

https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/mdJazoP

HTML

```
<div class="team-area">
        <div class="team-container">


            <a href="#">
                <span class="single-img img-one">
                    <span class="img-text">
                        <div class="img-text-upper-container">
                            <div class="img-text-title">
                                <h4>John Doe</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="img-text-price">
                                <h4 class="price">Lorem</h4>
                                <h4 class="date">10 days ago</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="img-description">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetssssgas...</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="img-options-inner">
                            <div class="img-options reviews">
                                <h5>4.5 <i class="far fa-star"></i></h5>
                            </div>


                            <div class="img-options comments">
                                <h5>10 <i class="far fa-comments"></i></h5>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>



            <a href="#">
                <span class="single-img img-two">
                    <span class="img-text">
                        <div class="img-text-upper-container">
                            <div class="img-text-title">
                                <h4>Jane Doe</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="img-text-price">
                                <h4 class="price">Lorem</h4>
                                <h4 class="date">10 days ago</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="img-description">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetssssgas...</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="img-options-inner">
                            <div class="img-options reviews">
                                <h5>4.5 <i class="far fa-star"></i></h5>
                            </div>


                            <div class="img-options comments">
                                <h5>10 <i class="far fa-comments"></i></h5>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>



            <a href="#">
                <span class="single-img img-three">
                    <span class="img-text">
                        <div class="img-text-upper-container">
                            <div class="img-text-title">
                                <h4>Baby Doe</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="img-text-price">
                                <h4 class="price">Lorem</h4>
                                <h4 class="date">10 days ago</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="img-description">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetssssgas...</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="img-options-inner">
                            <div class="img-options reviews">
                                <h5>4.5 <i class="far fa-star"></i></h5>
                            </div>


                            <div class="img-options comments">
                                <h5>10 <i class="far fa-comments"></i></h5>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>



            <a href="#">
                <span class="single-img img-four">
                    <span class="img-text">
                        <div class="img-text-upper-container">
                            <div class="img-text-title">
                                <h4>Mr. Doe</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="img-text-price">
                                <h4 class="price">Lorem</h4>
                                <h4 class="date">10 days ago</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="img-description">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetssssgas...</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="img-options-inner">
                            <div class="img-options reviews">
                                <h5>4.5 <i class="far fa-star"></i></h5>
                            </div>


                            <div class="img-options comments">
                                <h5>10 <i class="far fa-comments"></i></h5>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat:400,700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');

body{
    background: #1D1E22;
}


a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.team-area{
    padding: 48px 0 0 0;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.team-container{
    width: 1100px;
    height: auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.single-img{
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 325px;
    height: 260px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-bottom: 38px;
}

.single-img:hover{
    transform: translate(0, -9px);
}


.img-one{
  background: purple;
}

.img-two{
  background: green;
}

.img-three{
  background: blue;
}

.img-four{
  background: cyan;
}

.img-text {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(0, 68px);
    line-height: 10px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-text-upper-container{
    width: 100%;
}

.img-text-title{
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.img-text-price{
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}

.img-text-price h4 {
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 14px 0 0px 11px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.img-text-price .date {
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px 0 0px 11px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.img-text-price h4 span{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.img-text .img-description {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-text .img-description p {
    white-space: pre;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 22px 0 12px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.img-text p i{
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.img-text-title h4 {
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 12px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.img-text-title h5 {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: -12px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.single-img:hover .img-text{
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.img-options-inner{
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.img-options {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.img-options h5{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove `width: 1100px;`.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. I tried removing it but the items get stacked together without any spaces in between. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are not able to it because you have given a fixed to `div` `class="team-container"`.

Either Remove the `width` for `div` with `team-container` class or if you want it to be maximum then put it `max-width`. this should work for you

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat:400,700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');

body{
 background: #1D1E22;
}


a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #333;
}

.team-area{
 padding: 48px 0 0 0;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}

.team-container{
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content:flex-start;
}
.tile {
  margin:20px;
}
.single-img{
 border-radius: 5px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column-reverse;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 width: 325px;
 height: 260px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 overflow: hidden;
 transform: translate(0, 0);
 transition: 0.3s;
 margin-bottom: 38px;
}

.single-img:hover{
 transform: translate(0, -9px);
}


.img-one{
  background: purple;
}

.img-two{
  background: green;
}

.img-three{
  background: blue;
}

.img-four{
  background: cyan;
}

.img-text {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(0, 68px);
    line-height: 10px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-text-upper-container{
 width: 100%;
}

.img-text-title{
 float: left;
 width: 70%;
 padding-left: 0px;
}

.img-text-price{
 width: 30%;
 float: right;
}

.img-text-price h4 {
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 14px 0 0px 11px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.img-text-price .date {
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px 0 0px 11px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.img-text-price h4 span{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.img-text .img-description {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-text .img-description p {
    white-space: pre;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 22px 0 12px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.img-text p i{
 padding-right: 20px;
}

.img-text-title h4 {
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 12px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.img-text-title h5 {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: -12px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.single-img:hover .img-text{
 transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.img-options-inner{
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.img-options {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.img-options h5{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="team-area">
  <div class="team-container">


   <a href="#" class="tile">
    <span class="single-img img-one">
     <span class="img-text">
      <div class="img-text-upper-container">
       <div class="img-text-title">
        <h4>John Doe</h4>
       </div>

       <div class="img-text-price">
        <h4 class="price">Lorem</h4>
        <h4 class="date">10 days ago</h4>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="img-description">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetssssgas...</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="img-options-inner">
       <div class="img-options reviews">
        <h5>4.5 <i class="far fa-star"></i></h5>
       </div>


       <div class="img-options comments">
        <h5>10 <i class="far fa-comments"></i></h5>
       </div>

      </div>
      
     </span>
    </span>
   </a>



   <a href="#" class="tile">
    <span class="single-img img-two">
     <span class="img-text">
      <div class="img-text-upper-container">
       <div class="img-text-title">
        <h4>Jane Doe</h4>
       </div>

       <div class="img-text-price">
        <h4 class="price">Lorem</h4>
        <h4 class="date">10 days ago</h4>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="img-description">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetssssgas...</p>
      </div>

      <div class="img-options-inner">
       <div class="img-options reviews">
        <h5>4.5 <i class="far fa-star"></i></h5>
       </div>


       <div class="img-options comments">
        <h5>10 <i class="far fa-comments"></i></h5>
       </div>

      </div>
     </span>
    </span>
   </a>



   <a href="#" class="tile">
    <span class="single-img img-three">
     <span class="img-text">
      <div class="img-text-upper-container">
       <div class="img-text-title">
        <h4>Baby Doe</h4>
       </div>

       <div class="img-text-price">
        <h4 class="price">Lorem</h4>
        <h4 class="date">10 days ago</h4>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="img-description">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetssssgas...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-options-inner">
       <div class="img-options reviews">
        <h5>4.5 <i class="far fa-star"></i></h5>
       </div>


       <div class="img-options comments">
        <h5>10 <i class="far fa-comments"></i></h5>
       </div>

      </div>
     </span>
    </span>
   </a>



   <a href="#" class="tile">
    <span class="single-img img-four">
     <span class="img-text">
      <div class="img-text-upper-container">
       <div class="img-text-title">
        <h4>Mr. Doe</h4>
       </div>

       <div class="img-text-price">
        <h4 class="price">Lorem</h4>
        <h4 class="date">10 days ago</h4>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="img-description">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetssssgas...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-options-inner">
       <div class="img-options reviews">
        <h5>4.5 <i class="far fa-star"></i></h5>
       </div>


       <div class="img-options comments">
        <h5>10 <i class="far fa-comments"></i></h5>
       </div>

      </div>
     </span>
    </span>
   </a>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: hi thanks for replying. I tried max-width and at tablet size the items move in two directions with a huge gap in between. I mean two items in one column to the left and two items in another column to the right with a gap in between. Any solution to fix that?

Comment: I guess for this with this `margin: auto` will do the job. I have included this also in answer look for `class` I used  `tile` for your tile box and apply `margin: auto` to the box this will align the boxes automatically manage the distance between you profiles tiles.

Comment: I just used tile as you said. It solved the previous issue but now the fourth item is in the middle. I mean in the second column.

Comment: Hey in class `team-container` your CSS property `justify-content: space-between;` was creating the problem it was the reason for huge space in the middle. Remove the property and then add some desired margin in the `tile` class that should solve the issue for you. I have also included the same change in the answer.

Comment: It works but everything is left aligned now. The items are not centered. Is there a solution?